# Vim-plug plugin manager unable to use post-update hooks on YouCompleteMe plugin

Tags: python, linux, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I am using vim-plug plugin manager and it worked great until I tried to install Youcompleteme plugin with it. I tried putting `Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py' }` on my `.vimrc` and tried `PlugInstall!` and `PlugUpdate!` without success. I read the documentation from github and I thought it should work like that.

[image: Picture of the problem]

Althought I am unsure if this should be done by running `~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/install.py --all` in command line , as I am not using vundle.

Ps. My computer is using Arch Linux, but I don't think that it relates to this problem.

If you need more info please let me know!

Comment: Attach your image right

Answer (score 1):

First read the installation [instructions](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#ubuntu-linux-x64).

Make sure you have cmake and Python headers installed.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake python3-dev
```

As @tink suggested below use the package manager for your distribution instead of just running `apt-get`.

Remove the plugin and reinstall with `:PlugInstall`

You can also manually run:

```
~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/install.py
```

To find actual build errors.

BTW I have to run it like:

```
python3 install.py
```

Comment: And you need to read his post; he's on Arch, the tool for the installation job is `pacman`, not `apt-get`, no idea what the equivalent package (or task) would be called.

Comment: @tink I don't get paid to answer. Some people may still find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

It might be timing out while downloading.

You can clone Valloric/YouCompleteMe to .vim/plugged and then do the [Installation](http://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#installation).

You can still keep `Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` in you .vimrc, so it will update when the plugin gets updated.